# group generated by matrices of finite order

Tags: matrices, group-theory, permutations

Let $K$ be a field, and suppose $A,B$ are $n{\,\times\,}n$ matrices with coefficients in $K$ such that 
$$A^p =I\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;B^q=I$$
for some positive integers $p,q$.

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of matrices generated by $\{A,B\}$.

Two questions:

1. $\;$Must $G$ be finite?

   $\;$Assuming $G$ is finite, must $G$ be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_m$, where $m = \text{lcm}(p,q)$?

Since it appears that questions $(1)$ and $(2)$ both got quick "no" answers, I'll add one more question, a variant of question $(1)$:

$\;\;\;$3. What if $A,B$ also satisfy some multiplicative identity not algebraically derivable from $A^p=I$ and $B^q=I$. In other words, some word in $A,B,A^{-1},B^{-1}$ is equal to $I$. Now must $G$ be finite?

Based on the answers already given for questions $(1)$ and $(2)$, I'm not optimistic about the chances for a "yes" answer to question $(3)$.

Thanks for the responses so far.

Comment: You can view $A$ as an element $a$ with $a^p = e$ and $B$ as an element $b$ with $b^q = e$.

Comment: The answer to Qn is no even when $n=1$. If $p$ and $q$ are different primes then the smallest $m$ with $G \le S_m$ is $p+q$.

Comment: I should have said $\text{lcm}$, not $\max$ -- I'll edit that in, if you don't mind.

Comment: For Qn 3, no,  there are infinite subgroups $\langle A,B \rangle$ of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb C})$ with $A^l=B^m=(AB)^n$ for all sufficiently large values of $l.m.n$.

Comment: Thanks. I think my questions are now resolved, at least the ones in this thread. I may have some more group-theoretic questions in the future. Thanks again, and thanks to all for their inputs.

Comment: I guess if $AB=BA$ then $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 8):

No, already for $p=q=2$, the infinite dihedral group
$$
C_2\ast C_2=D_{\infty}=\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=e\rangle
$$
is a counter-example.

Edit: We can take the matrices $$A=\left(\begin{array}[cc] .1 & -1\\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad B=\left(\begin{array}[cc].1&0\\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right).$$ Both have order $2$, but their product gives $$(AB)^n=\left(\begin{array}[cc] .1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),$$
so that $AB$ has infinite order.

Comment: But can you explicitly construct $K$, $A$, and $B$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need to produce two matrices $A$ and $B$ of order $2$ such that $AB$ has infinite order.. The answer to Qn 2 is also no, because the product could have arbitrarily large finite order.

Comment: Thanks. I expected a no answer for question (1). I may add a variant of question (1), but I'll leave that question intact since your answer resolves it.

Comment: @quasi you should validate this very good answer.